# How to auto fill cell C with a formula that only returns the date from cell a?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently my google spreadsheet has cell `B` & `A` which contains my timestamp and temperature value which I send from my Arduino. I am unable to display it out on my google chart because it only takes in number range filter or date range filter, so I have to convert the timestamp to only a time as the date is not important.

I created a formula in cell `C` which is `=int(A2)` which returns me the date, and in cell `D` `=C2-A2` which returns me the actual time that I wanted to use in my google chart. But when my arduino sends a new timestamp and temp value, the cells `C` and `D` do not auto update and convert for me.

Is there anything I can do to make cell 'C' and 'D' auto calculate and do the formula when my Arduino sends new data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array formulae for this.

In A2 you can put

```
=ArrayFormula(C2:C-A2:A)
```

If you want non filled cells not to display 0 you can

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C2:C), C2:C-A2:A, ""))
```

Comment: Hi Mr Robin! I have tried to put in your formula but it returns me #REF! at A2, and "Error. Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A3". Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only need to put the formula in the first cell, everything below needs to be empty as it will auto-fill downwards